# Ansible Remote File Copy wildcard

Tags: copy, ansible

Lets say i have this dirs and files:

```
Dir1/File1    - Local on my ansible host

Dir1/SubDir1/File1 
Dir2/SubDir2/            - Remote Server 
Dir3/SubDir3/File1 
...
```

How is in ansible the right way to copy the local file to all remote subdirs and to specify the remote dirs as wildcard.

Before copying it should do a backup of the existing files in their dirs.

As result i want to find File1 in all SubDirs.

Regards

Comment: Find all subdirs with recursive `find` module, register output and then copy file in a loop using `with_items`.

Comment: Thx Konstantin ! Can you give me an example.

Comment: I'm afraid no, sorry.

Comment: No Problem. Maybe someone else can write an example.

Comment: You can find plenty of them at docs.ansible.com. You can start [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html#examples).

Answer (score 0):

To create the backup of the remote file before you replace the file , you can use the 'backup' parameter in copy module. And for using wildcards you can use the fileglob parameter.

You can refer the following links.
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id17